# Crypto-Trader.com Shut down. Did I loose all my Coins?

Tags: wallet, exchanges, fraud

The Exchange Crypto-Trader shut down sometime I believe in 2015. I was never notified by the shutdown. There are reports out there that they sent all their users an e-mail giving 48 hours to withdraw their coins however I never received shut e-mail and never withdrew. At this point is there anything I could do?

Answer (score 1):

A similar type of event happened with [Mt. Gox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mt._Gox) where users lost a total of 850 000 Bitcoins. Your Bitcoins are likely lost forever if the owner of the private keys does not agree to send them to you. However, you may be able to sue the exchange, but I am no legal advice. Take this as a lesson, to never keep a cryptocurrency on an exchange, it is very important to own your coins.

Answer (score 1):

Letting your Bitcoins on an exchange means trusting the exchange. That's the reason why you should send them to an adress of your wallet.
You can't probably do anything to get them back.